# How to make Vhost in apache-tomcat-8.5.14 NOT apache2

Tags: apache, tomcat, centos

I have searched about making Vhost in apache-tomcat-8.5.14 but didn't find a solution for the problem i'm facing. The problem is, I have installed apache-tomcat-8.5.14 in Centos, want to make Vhost into this but can't find the basic directory where the httpd config files. If I install the httpd separatey it prompts that this is already install. How come I make Vhost in apache-tomcat-8.5.14?

Comment: Does that mean you want Apache httpd *and* tomcat serve the same port?

Comment: I dont know what httpd have to do here. I followed a tutorial that says I need httpd to have vhost.. My ultimate question is to how come I configure Vhost in server.xml? secondly, Where do I have to deploy my PHP website and give its directory in server.xml